# Scala: Default value for trait method not accepted

Tags: scala

I have defined a method in a trait:

```
trait myTrait {
  def myMethod(entity: Entity = null, name: String)
}

val t = ....//concrete implementation of myTrait
t.myMethod("John")
```

I have provided default value of null for entity in method definition.

This give compilation error as: Type mismatch, required MyCustomClass found String

Why is it so?

Comment: You usually put parameters with default value at the end. I actually thought this was enforced by the compiler btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the name of your argument.

`t.myMethod(name = "John")`

It also works for case class when you want to `.copy`

```
case class MyStruct(a: String, b: String)

val a = MyStruct("foo", "bar")
val b = a.copy(b = "clazz")
```

See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/named-arguments.html

Also, in scala, the presence / absence of value is usually represented by `Option[T]` like

```
def myMethod(entity: Option[Entity] = None, ... )
```